# Creation of AppDomain Crashes build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get AppDomains working in my Unity project, and it is turning out nice, everything works perfectly in the editor. Once I make a build it crashes once I call

```
AppDomain domain1 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain1");
```

I hard crash, and looking at the crash.dmp file that was generated the only useful information I have is

> "The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which
>   it does not have the appropriate access."

I have compiled the exact same code in .net and mono (both in release) and they work fine. So I would have to assume it is a Unity specific bug, or a setting that is present in default projects is not present in Unity.

Comment: Does Unity3D support apps creating child `AppDomain`s?

Comment: When running it in the Editor AppDomain does work properly. Even after compilation Assembly.Load does work, so it appears that Unity Does not have any intentional decisions to block systems like this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54281115/appdomain-support-is-dead-in-unityengine-any-way-to-unload-dll